# Django decorators @transaction_atomic & @static_method interfere with each other?

Tags: python, django, static-methods, atomic, python-decorators

My Django Model:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field1 = models.IntegerField()

    @staticmethod
    def my_method():
        return "XXXX"
```

As you can see, when I run `my_method()`, it works:

```
>>> MyModel.my_method()
'XXXX'
```

But then I add the decorator `@transaction_atomic` to `my_method()`:

```
@transaction.atomic
@staticmethod
def my_method():
    return "XXXX"
```

Now when I try to do the same thing, it now fails:

```
>>> MyModel.my_method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Why?? How should I fix it.
I would like the `my_method()` to be both a static method and atomic.

Comment: What happens if you switch the decorators around, with `@staticmethod` as the outermost decorator?

Comment: @knbk That worked!!!!